# How to pass a string as a parameter to a function which expects a variable in R

Tags: r, data.table, nse

The first call to the function f works, the second does not. How can I pass a String ("v") to the function f so that the function works as exspected?

```
library(data.table)

f<-function(t,x) t[,deparse(substitute(x)),with=F]

dat<-data.table(v="a")

f(dat,v)
#    v
# 1: a

f(dat,eval(parse(text="v")))
# Error in `[.data.table`(t, , deparse(substitute(x)), with = F) : 
#   column(s) not found: eval(parse(text = "v"))
```

Comment: Use `mget()` as in `dat[, mget(col)]` or `.SD` along with `.SDcols` as in `dat[, .SD, .SDcols=cols]` where `cols = "v"`. Allowing the same function argument to have a symbol (of column) *and* as a character vector is inviting trouble and ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be a one-liner anymore but you can test for what you're passing in:

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

dat <- data.table(v="a")

f <- function(dt, x) {

  # first, see if 'x' is a variable holding a string with a column name

  seval <- safely(eval)
  res <- seval(x, dt, parent.frame())

  # if it is, then get the value, otherwise substitute() it

  if ((!is.null(res$result)) && inherits(res$result, "character")) {
    y <- res$result
  } else {
    y <- substitute(x)
  }

  # if it's a bare name, then we deparse it, otherwise we turn
  # the string into name and then deparse it

  if (inherits(y, "name")) {
    y <- deparse(y) 
  } else if (inherits(y, "character")) {
    y <- deparse(as.name(x))
  }

  dt[, y, with=FALSE]

}

f(dat,v)
##    v
## 1: a

f(dat, "v")
##    v
## 1: a

V <- "v"
f(dat, V)
##    v
## 1: a

f(dat, VVV)
#> throws an Error
```

I switched it from `t` to `dt` since I don't like using the names of built-in functions (like `t()`) as variable names unless I really have to. It can introduce subtle errors in larger code blocks that can be frustrating to debug.

I'd also move the `safely()` call outside the `f()` function to save a function call each time you run `f()`. You can use old-school `try()` instead, if you like, but you have to check for `try-error` which may break some day. You could also `tryCatch()` wrap it, but the `safely()` way just seems cleaner to me.

Comment: `dt` is also the name of a built-in function!! stupid t-distribution. i prefer `DT`

Comment: true, but it's far more likely that one is going to want to transpose data than use the Student t distribution (at least in my usage :-)